# Handling account name collisions between multiple 3rd party oauth providers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, owin

I am using OWIN with MVC 5 to handle multiple 3rd party identity providers, including Facebook, LinkedIn, and Google accounts.

My ApplicationUser is currently inheriting the default IdentityUser, which seems to put a uniqueness constraint on the email field.

If I login to my site using Facebook, my usename is set to "john@hotmail.com". Then if I come back to the site and try to auth using google, not surprisingly I get the following two errors:

```
Name john@hotmail.com is already taken.
Email 'john@hotmail.com' is already taken.
```

Ideally I would merge these two identities into one account that has 2 types of oauth methods enabled.

I am not very familiar with the Microsoft Identity model - is there a path of least resistance for accomplishing my goal?

One concern I have is handling the case where an attacker registers a linkedin account with "john@hotmail.com" (if I don't have one) and uses that method to try to auth to my site. In that case, I would need to send verification emails every time the user tries to add a new auth method before doing the merge.

Edit:

Doing some more digging I found that my user config has these options defined

```
manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };
```

Wondering if this is desirable. If the end user has different email addresses applied to their Facebook vs. LinkedIn profiles it might just make a bigger mess.

Comment: Maybe the easiest thing to do in the example above is to redirect the user to the facebook login when they try to login with the google account and the emails collide? Then use the existing 3rd party login management page to add the google login as well?

Comment: One nice thing about using the Email as the username is that creating a local login from a 3rd party login is easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UserManager` exposes the `AddLoginAsync` method for the purpose of adding another login method to an existing user. In my authentication server I permit users to log in via any method as long as the email address is the same.

Regarding creating a fake account, anyone who is providing OAuth2 authorization services ought to be verifying emails before permitting these services to be used. Google and Facebook do; I'm assuming LinkedIn do as well but not sure. The provider may also expose an email_verified claim or similar, which you can check to be on the safe side.